# Pause download on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I'm a Nexus 4 user. I tried to download Injustice from Google Play Store last night and it got cancelled a couple of times due to poor speed of my connection. Is there a way to pause the download so that I could later complete the download?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct switch to do so. As @r4d1um says, you may deactivate your data, and once you want to resume, restart your data and the store will start download from where you had left off.

Answer (score 0):

You may deactivate your mobile data, activate again when the download has stopped and set Google Play for not updating Apps automatically then you can set this option again when youre connected through wifi again or set that Apps can be updated via WiFi only.

Comment: Thanks that was useful. But is there a way that i could  resume download if it got cancelled or automatically pause the download when it gets a networ error....??

Comment: There is no direct switch to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Custom ROMs like "Liquid Smooth" allow pausing and resuming explicitly.

I have tried it personally, I had Nexus 4. Google Play downloads are managed by media download manager, so they've added pause/resume functionality to that.

Comment: How do these ROMs add features to the Play Store?

Comment: I  have tried personally, I  had nexus 4 b4, now broken. Google play downloads are managed by media download manager, so they've added pause resume functionality to that.